# Inserting value from VARRAY in pl/SQL DROP query

Tags: plsql, velocity

I am trying to populate a array through a select query and then dropping values grabbed in select query.

```
DECLARE 
TYPE name_list is varray(20) of VARCHAR2(30);
existingConstraints name_list:=name_list();
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_constraint_exists FROM user_constraints  
WHERE constraint_name != 'some_value'  AND table_name = 'some_value';

for i in NVL(existingConstraints.FIRST,0)..NVL(existingConstraints.LAST,-1) loop
  #set($name=existingConstraints(i))
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ${some_value} DROP CONSTRAINT ${name} DROP INDEX';
end loop;

END
```

But i am getting Exception. Can someone suggest me right approach for the same.

Comment: Above is wrong code for select query i am using:
 SELECT constraint_name INTO existingConstraints FROM user_constraints  
 WHERE constraint_name != 'some_value'  AND table_name = 'some_value' AND constraint_type='U';

Comment: Any particular exception?

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "existingConstraints" at INSTALLER/PCT_OBJECT_FIELDS/objectFieldsUKconstraints.vm[line 67, column 14]
Was expecting one of:
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    "(" ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "{" ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...

Answer (score 0):

```
`DECLARE
TYPE name_list is varray(20) of VARCHAR2(30);
existingConstraints name_list:=name_list();

BEGIN

SELECT constraint_name INTO existingConstraints FROM user_constraints  
WHERE constraint_name != 'some_value'  AND table_name = 'some_value' AND constraint_type='U';

for i in NVL(existingConstraints.FIRST,0)..NVL(existingConstraints.LAST,-1) loop
#set($name=existingConstraints(i))
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ${tableName} DROP CONSTRAINT ${name} DROP INDEX';
end loop;

END`
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a slightly different way but problem solved, just for the reference.

```
DECLARE
TYPE name_list is table of VARCHAR2(30);
v_constraint_exists NUMBER;
existingConstraints name_list:=name_list();
dropConstraintName VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN

SELECT constraint_name bulk collect INTO existingConstraints FROM user_constraints  
WHERE constraint_name != 'some_name'  AND table_name = 'some_name' AND constraint_type='U';


for i in NVL(existingConstraints.FIRST,0)..NVL(existingConstraints.LAST,-1) loop
  dropConstraintName:=existingConstraints(i);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ${tableName} DROP CONSTRAINT '||dropConstraintName||' DROP INDEX';
end loop;

END
```